# PHP GD , resize , quality , save , png , jpg and gif

Tags: php, image-resizing

I see many function for resize with gd , but my question it´s for know if exists some function or class i can use and for example upload image , jpg , jpeg , png or gif , and can resize this with the width and height i want , determinate the quality of that image and finally save in the folder determinated and with the same extension to the image i upload , if upload png image , save png image resized and with the quality i want , etc

I see many functions but in all cases no have these variables

- Resize image - determinate width and height
- Determinate Quality
- Determinate path folder to save and save with the same extension

In many cases upload png and save as jpg and create jpg from png , etc

I search but no find for this , thank´s if you can help me

The best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resizing:** [imagecopyresampled()](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.imagecopyresampled.php)
**Saving:** [imagegif()](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.imagegif.php), [imagejpeg()](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.imagejpeg.php), [imagepng()](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.imagepng.php)

I don't think you can actually "determine" quality of the image.
Once it's exported out of graphics software, you can't really tell if it's full quality or like 76% of it.

**You can set quality when saving into .jpeg file tho.**

```
$quality = 90;
imagejpeg($image, 'output.jpeg', $quality);
```